# Selecting elements of a named vector using dplyr/tidyr

Tags: r

Very simple question that I can't figure out for some reason.

I have a named vector:

```
dat <- c("Clyde" = 1, "Susy" = 2, "Frank" = 3, "John" = 4)
```

How do I select just Clyde and Frank's numbers using `dplyr`? The code below doesn't seem to be doing it.

```
dat %>% select(Clyde, Frank)
```

Am sure its a super easy solution, just can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` works when the data is `data.frame` and not on named `vector`.  One option would be to convert to a two column `tibble` with `enframe` (from `tibble`), `filter` the 'name' columns and then `deframe` to create the named `vector`

```
library(tibble)
librarry(dplyr)
dat %>%
    enframe %>% 
    filter(name %in% c("Clyde", "Frank")) %>%
    deframe
#  Clyde Frank 
#   1     3
```

---

If we are using `magrittr` another option is `extract` (not that there is a similar function in `tidyr` - behaviour different) which is alias for `[`

```
library(magrittr)
dat %>%
    extract(c("Clyde", "Frank"))
#   Clyde Frank 
#    1     3
```

---

Or if we want to use `select`, convert it to a 4 -column data.frame/tibble

```
dat %>% 
    t %>% 
    as_tibble %>%
    select(Clyde, Frank)
```

Here, we convert it to a `matrix` first with transposing the vector (as `vector` and `matrix` can hold only a single class, it is  okay), then convert it to a `tibble` (`as_tibble`) and use `select` to select the columns with unquoted column names

---

In `base R`, it is simply using the `names`

```
dat[c("Clyde", "Frank")]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Always coming through with a solution! Really appreciate it!